# Cause of Magnetization of an object when placed in an external magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm a bit confused on the topic of causality in general when speaking of the 3 fields $\mathbf{B},\mathbf{H},\mathbf{M}$, i.e. which causes which.

In particular, I've heard my professor say  that $\mathbf{H}$ causes $\mathbf{M}$. I'm confused if that's the case, as I think that in general, its an external magnetic field $\mathbf{B_{ext}}$ which causes a material to be magnetized (when placed in it) and $\mathbf{B_{ext}}$ is not necessarily equal to $\mathbf{H}$. Is this correct? If so, when does the equivalence hold?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{B}_{ext}$ is the field that exists in vacuum without the magnetic material occupying the same space, there is no ambiguity in what that means; it satisfies both $\textbf{curl}\textbf{B}_{ext}=\mu_0\textbf{J}$ and $\textrm{div}\textbf{B}_{ext}=0$. Here $\textbf{J}$ is the current that is used to generate the biasing fields $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{H}$ *inside* the material and causes it to be magnetized for "soft", or adds to its own permanent magnetization for "hard" materials. In either case, the two fields are not the same.

In a magnetizable material surface poles of density $\textrm{div}\textbf{M}$ are developed that induce a *demagnetizing* field $\textbf{H}_d=\textbf{H} - \textbf{B}_{ext}/\mu_0$that is in general has the opposite direction to its magnetization $\textbf{M}$, hence the name. Unfortunately, the actual inside demagnetizing field, hence what the outside field is, depends also on the *shape* of the material; one could just as well say that the surface pole distribution depends on the shape. As a result there is no general relationship between what outside or inside the composite field $\textbf{B}$ (including $\textbf{B}_{ext}$) is and what generates the field $\textbf{B}_{ext}$ (or if you wish $\textbf{J}$).

But if we know what the inside demagnetizing field $\textbf{H}_d$ is at every point then we would know $\textbf{H}$ and then there would be a material dependent (not shape dependent) local pointwise relationship between $\textbf{B}$ and $\textbf{H}$ at every point of the magnetizable material.

This relationship cannot be measured unless we know how the demagnetizing field depends on the external field. For a very high permeability material that has almost no leakage field in a closed torus (or most any permeability torus but with a very tightly wound coil around it) the demagnetizing field is essentially zero and then the external field is almost identical to the internal field. If the material is ellipsoidal shape and the external field is homogeneous again we know what happens. In other cases we do not have simple formulas.